# Mockito - getting wrong mocked result when the mocked method has parent instance as parameters

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I would like to use mockito to mock some external rest service in my code. 
My code structure contains a **BaseParams** class which is a parent class for all request parameters that I am using, a **BaseResponse** which is a parent class for all response that I receive from the rest service.

Now I would like to mock 2 requests: **getCountries** and **getLanguages** which needed **CountriesParams** and **LanguagesParams** as request params (both extend **BaseParams**), and the response will be **CountriesResponse** and **LanguagesResponse** which both also extend **BaseResponse**.

The method I would like to mock has a signiture:

```
public BaseResponse sendRequest(BaseParams baseParams, Settings settings, String serviceUrl, BaseResponse baseResponse){
         ...here some calls to external rest service will be performed...
    return baseResponse;
}
```

Below is my mock setup:

```
        RequestManager requestManager = Mockito.spy(new RequestManager());

        doReturn(MockFactory.mockCountriesResponse())//
                .when(requestManager)//
                .sendRequest(any(CountriesParams.class), any(), eq("service/getCountries"), any(CountriesResponse.class));

        doReturn(MockFactory.mockLanguagesResponse())//
                .when(requestManager)//
                .sendRequest(any(LanguagesParams.class), any(), eq("service/getLanguages"), any(LanguagesResponse.class));
```

The problem that I am facing is when I call the testCountries, it returned a CastException:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.project.client.responses.LanguagesResponse cannot be cast to
>   com.project.client.responses.CountriesResponse

I think the problem is because the mock settup can not distinguish between which mock result it needs to take here, because the mock method has BaseResponse and BaseParams als parameters which are so abstract.

Can any give me an idea how can I correct the mock params in my mock method so that it can get the right mock result. Thank you in advanced

Comment: We're not extra-lucid wizards. Post all the relevant code, and the exact and complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Which version of Mockito do you have?  I'd expect this in version 1.x, but not version 2.x.  If you're seeing this in version 2.x, I'd try out the Mockito mailing list.  It's possible you've discovered a Mockito bug, and the developers would appreciate knowing about it.